# Can't flip bitmap when calling ID2D1DeviceContext::DrawBitmap

Tags: bitmap, directx, directx-11, direct2d

I have the following code to draw a bitmap on Direct2D context:

```
ID2D1DeviceContext * pContext;  // initialization omitted
ID2D1Bitmap1 * pBitmap;         // initialization omitted
pContext->DrawBitmap(pBitmap, NULL, 1.f, D2D1_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, NULL, NULL);
```

This works fine, but I need my image to be **flipped vertically**, so I tried this:

```
D2D_MATRIX_4X4_F flip = D2D1::Matrix4x4F::RotationY(180);
pContext->DrawBitmap(pBitmap, NULL, 1.f, D2D1_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, NULL, &flip);
```

But now the bitmap is not being drawn at all. When I provide an *identity* matrix instead, it works. When I try to replace the `y` value in the matrix from `1` to `-1` it fails again (I believe it's the same as making Rotation matrix in the original code snippet).

Also tried to provide the `D2D_RECT_F` struct for `destinationRectangle`, and tried to switch between the *top* and *bottom* values in the rect - same problem remains.

Any insides are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the "perspectiveTransform" parameter of DrawBitmap means, but the traditional way of using transforms in Direct2D does work:

```
const D2D1_SIZE_F& size = pContext->GetSize();
D2D1_POINT_2F center = D2D1::Point2F(size.width / 2.0f, size.height / 2.0f);

pContext->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(180.0f, center);
pContext->DrawBitmap(pBitmap);
pContext->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());
```

Note that this uses the ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawBitmap method, not ID2D1DeviceContext::DrawBitmap (though either one should work, just don't use the perspectiveTransform parameter). I tested this and it works.

Another way of doing this, perhaps more efficiently, is to first create a WIC bitmap (IWICBitmapSource), rotate it by using IWICBitmapFlipRotator, and then create a ID2D1Bitmap from the rotator by using ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap. For a demonstration of this, see [How to Flip and Rotate a Bitmap Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719659(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Why is this marked as answer? This does a 180 degrees rotate, not a vertical flip..